# Renaming a class in retrospect?

Tags: xcode, refactoring, rename, automated-refactoring

To be on the safe side, and as my project is relatively small, when I wanted to change the name of a class in Swift, I changed it manually and went through the files individually - storyboard, class file, and in project navigator.

In Xcode, is there another way to do this to be sure of replacing all instances, or is manually the only way to go? Can you safely use a find and replace for this purpose?

Comment: Until the method Duncan has described works for Swift, the safest approach is probably to go to the definition and rename it their first.  Everywhere else *should* throw errors unless there's scoping issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the class name in the declaration, right-click/control click on it, choose "refactor" and select "rename". That will do a complete rename, including references to the class from your storyboards. It's much safer than doing it manually (assuming the Swift editor is as smart as the Objective-C editor - I'm still pretty new to Swift development, so I haven't tested this feature with Swift.)

[image]

(As of version 6.2, Xcode is only capable of doing this with Objective-C and C code.)

Comment: Just tried doing that in Swift and I got an alert saying that refactoring can only be done in C and Objective-C in Xcode :(

Comment: Let's all file bug reports saying that code refactoring doesn't work in Swift. It should.

Comment: Still great to know how to do it in Objective-C and I use that more than Swift also.

Comment: If you guys are still checking in here - how does the find and replace all method work compare to this refactoring method in objective-c? Is the latter more reliable?